# Jquery datatable get row id from button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have two buttons rendered on each row in my datatable, Edit and Delete. Is it possible to grab the employee's ID or the Row's ID on the Delete or Edit button click and have it passed that id value into a webmethod I have that takes in an ID parameter to delete a record off the database?

My jquery code so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("GetEmployee.aspx") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'Id' },
                        { 'data': 'image' },
                        { 'data': 'lastName' },
                        { 'data': 'firstName' },
                        { 'data': 'jobTitle' },
                        {
                            'data': 'StartDate',
                            'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': 'EndDate',
                            'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': null,
                            'render': function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<button id="' + row.id +'" onclick="editClick()">Edit</button>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': null,
                            'render': function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<button id="' + row.id + '" class="dodo" onclick="deleteClick()">Delete</button>'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });

        $('#datatable').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var id = $(this).data();
            //var id = table.row($(this)).data();
            alert(JSON.stringify(id));
        });
    });
```

Right now its returning my an undefined when I try to grab the id.

My webmethod:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static void DeleteRecord(string id)
    {
        var query = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE ID=?";
        OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection(myConnection);
        OdbcTransaction transaction = null;
        myConn.Open();

        transaction = myConn.BeginTransaction();
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, myConn, transaction);
        command.Parameters.Add("ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = id;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Commit();

        myConn.Close();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get both employee's ID or the row's ID upon button click. For this you need to perform some minor changes when defining edit and delete button.

```
{
     'data': null,
     'render': function (data, type, row) {
                   return '<button id="' + row.id +'" onclick="editClick(this)">Edit</button>'
               }
},
{
     'data': null,
     'render': function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<button id="' + row.id + '" class="dodo" onclick="deleteClick(this)">Delete</button>'
               }
}
```

> Javascript / jQuery

```
function editClick (obj) {
      var rowID = $(obj).attr('id');
      var employeeID = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td:first').html());
}

function deleteClick (obj) {
      var rowID = $(obj).attr('id');
      var employeeID = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td:first').html());
}
```

Comment: You can do this more easily using `jquery`.

Comment: Thanks for replying and Yes, It can be done but here OP just want a solution to pass either employee id or row id. So, this is one the way to obtain it. Rest is upto OP to choose suitable answer.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Hey, thanks this worked perfectly. I'll accept this one as the answer as I tried the others and it didn't work for me. Thanks everyone else for contributing though. Appreciate it.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Out of curiosity how would I do this in jquery?

Comment: @SC.Cee, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @SC.Cee: Please have a look at my answer It's already in jQuery. What Alexandru-Ionut Mihai suggested, there are more better ways to get row id in comparison to what I have done. If you try by yourself you can get a more simplified version even better than mine.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Ah cool thanks, one problem I have right now just noticed it, when i click on the 2nd rows or 3rd rows it always gives me back 1.

Comment: @SC.Cee: Can you be more specific what is this value 1, this will be more helpful.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal When i alert employeeID on button click, it just gives displays 1 for every row i click? and when i try to alert rowID it just says undefined as well.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai have just updated this post you (Sc.Cee) can have a look at it till then I will come up with some minor tweaks.

Comment: @SC.Cee: Please have a look at my code again. Did some changes, It will work now. One more thing if `row.id` is undefined then I guess when this section gets render into HTML the button tag is missing ID attribute. Check your browser developer console.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Thanks, your latest changes worked.

Comment: Pleasure helping you out. Kindly do check for undefined issue as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal , What if i used anchor tag and id, value already in use to specify some other data-points? Like: return "<a class='process-leave-bymgr' value='1' name='"+row.hashed_id+"'> <i class='far fa-check-circle customizedicon'></i></a>";

Comment: This is a good answer, but if your button ends up in a child row due to - for instance - a responsive design, then you no longer can capture the data from the TR using this method.

Answer (score 4):

*it's Possible i know three ways.*

**1 bad ways: go data for backEnd for example** Disadvantages shorting and search... function disabled. extra response.

```
<a data-id="<?=yourQueryResult["id"]?>" onclick="javascript:foo()"></a>
function foo (){ var id = $(this)attr("data-id")}
```

or

```
<a onclick="javascript:foo(<?=yourQueryResult["id"]?>)"></a>
function foo(id){ /*deleting*/}
```

**2 on render function go javascript method parameters row id**
example

```
render': function (data, type, row) {
                   return '<a onclick="javascript:foo('+ row.id +')"></a>'
               }
```

**3 My favoritte direck jquery event listener to get row data
Advantages: clean html, no inline function calling and all your function same file calling.**

```
var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({...})

$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'a.delete', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
            var id = row.data().yourColumnName;
        });
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'a.edit', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                var rowData = row.data();
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.attr()` method in order to find out `id` attribute.

```
$('#datatable').on('click', 'button.deleteButton', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
$('#datatable').on('click', 'button.editButton', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Datatable

```
 {
       'data': null,
        'render': function (data, type, row) {
               return '<button id="' + row.id +'" class="editButton">Edit</button>'
        }
 },
 {
       'data': null,
       'render': function (data, type, row) {
           return '<button id="' + row.id + '" class="deleteButton" >Delete</button>'
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried this way and when I did the alert it gave me undefined.

Comment: Also, do you remove `deleteClick()` and `editClick()` ?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't. You have to remove those? EDIT: removed the onclicks still doesn't work?

Comment: Hmmm, it's still giving me undefined even now. Is another part of my code doing this? I'm just trying to alert to see what values I get and it's been giving me undefined even with this updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add data-id to a button like this:

```
'<button data-id="' + row.id + '" id="' + row.id + '" class="dodo" onclick="deleteClick()">Delete</button>'
```

same for other button and then on click:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

this will brings your Id

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Get Row and its first parameter is your id and pass it into your deleteclick function

 {
        'data': null,
            'render': function (data, type, row) 
             {
                var id = row.id;
                return '<button id="' + row.id + '" class="dodo" onclick="deleteClick("' + id + '")">Delete</button>'
             }
 }

function deleteClick(var id)
{
      alert(id);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("GetEmployee.aspx") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'Id' },
                        { 'data': 'image' },
                        { 'data': 'lastName' },
                        { 'data': 'firstName' },
                        { 'data': 'jobTitle' },
                        {
                            'data': 'StartDate',
                            'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': 'EndDate',
                            'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': null,
                            'render': function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<button id="' + row.id +'" onclick="editClick()">Edit</button>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': null,
                            'render': function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<button id="' + row.id + '" class="dodo" onclick="deleteClick()">Delete</button>'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
  var data = table.row($(this)).data();
  alert(id[0]);//0 is column number starting from 0.
});
```

This will work 100%

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: explain your code.